# Memory Leak Rails/Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, memory-leaks, mongodb, delayed-job

What sort of tools are available to monitor memory usage in methods running from delayed_job?

I have looked at memorylogic, oink, bleakhouse but they all either seem designed to work with controllers or I am missing something. Any examples of how delayed_job memory leaks (not with the gem itself but the code it is running) are detected will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I used memprof.

[Profile a delayed_job task in a Ruby on Rails app/Memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051678/profile-a-delayed-job-task-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app-memory-leak/4051740#4051740)