# Profile a delayed_job task in a Ruby on Rails app/Memory leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, profiling, delayed-job

One of my delayed_job tasks has a serious memory leak and I'm having a hard time solving it.
Can anyone recommend a good tool for profile a delayed_job task in order to solve this memory leak?

Regards,
Rubem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use memprof.

Here's a tutorial about it: http://timetobleed.com/memprof-a-ruby-level-memory-profiler/

Comment: You can try to do same in Ruby :)